# Nested class in JSON de-serialization using marshmallow

Tags: python, json, deserialization, marshmallow

How would I de-serialize nested JSON using marshmallow so that I can use dot notation like `app.data.person.lname`? Currently my example works only one level down, but I can't get last name (`lname`) from the nested `person` structure:

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, post_load
import datetime as dt
import json

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, fname, lname):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname

class PersonSchema(Schema):
    fname = fields.Str()
    lname = fields.Str()

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, appid, channel, person):
        self.appid = appid
        self.channel = channel
        self.person = person
        self.created_at = dt.datetime.now()

class AppSchema(Schema):
    appid = fields.Str()
    channel = fields.Str()
    person = fields.Nested(PersonSchema)
    created_at = fields.DateTime()

    @post_load
    def make_user(self, data):
        return App(**data)

json_data = """{
    "appid": "2309wfjwef",
    "channel": "retail",
    "person": {
        "fname": "John",
        "lname": "Doe"
        }
}"""

app_data = json.loads(json_data)

schema = AppSchema()
app = schema.load(app_data)

print(app.data.person.lname)
```

Getting:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'lname'
```

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, you need to create `Person` in `PersonSchema`:

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, post_load
import datetime as dt
import json

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, fname, lname):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname

class PersonSchema(Schema):
    fname = fields.Str()
    lname = fields.Str()

    @post_load
    def make_person(self, data):
        return Person(**data)


class App(object):
    def __init__(self, appid, channel, person):
        self.appid = appid
        self.channel = channel
        self.person = person
        self.created_at = dt.datetime.now()

class AppSchema(Schema):
    appid = fields.Str()
    channel = fields.Str()
    person = fields.Nested(PersonSchema)
    created_at = fields.DateTime()

    @post_load
    def make_app(self, data):
        return App(**data)

json_data = """{
    "appid": "2309wfjwef",
    "channel": "retail",
    "person": {
        "fname": "John",
        "lname": "Doe"
        }
}"""

app_data = json.loads(json_data)

schema = AppSchema()
app = schema.load(app_data)

print(app.data.person.fname)
```

Comment: Hint: you could have all your schemas inherit from a BseSchema with a `make_object` `@post_load` method. In each schema, set the model class as a class attribute: `OBJECT_CLS = Person`, and in `BaseSchema.make_object`: `return self.OBJEC_CLS(**data)`.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to Tomas Greif's last post, I get an error:
TypeError: make_app() got an unexpected keyword argument 'many'

Until I added the argument to the @post_load functions like:

```
def make_person(self, data, **kwargs):
```

and

```
def make_app(self, data, **kwargs):
```

and then there was an additional error AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'data', so I removed the data from the print statement:

```
print(app.person.fname)
```

AFter those changes, the code ran without errors.